# Material Datepicker change month view event

Tags: angular-material2

is there any way how to detect that calendar has new month view is loaded, when "yellow buttons" (see screenshot) are used?

[image]

Comment: Have you found a way to tap into those events?

Comment: Hello. I just listen on click of these buttons and I use async (setTimeout) while content is reloaded. But this is not super smart solution. But it works for now.

Comment: [Try catching Keyboard Input Events as described in Documentation!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tDqq.png) Here's documentation link, https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview

Answer (score 4):

You can listen for click events of those buttons on the calendar using Renderer2.

Code from [this blog post](https://onthecode.co.uk/angular-material-calendar-component/).

```
constructor( private renderer: Renderer2g) { }

ngAfterViewInit() {
    let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('mat-calendar .mat-calendar-previous-button,' +
        'mat-calendar .mat-calendar-next-button');

    if (buttons) {
        Array.from(buttons).forEach(button => {
            this.renderer.listen(button, "click", () => {
                console.log("Month changed");
            });
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: This is listen on click. I need to know that new content was loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use your own header component with whatever buttons and events your want:

```
<mat-calendar [headerComponent]="headerComponent"></mat-calendar>
```

And declare a variable headerComponent in the .ts:

```
public headerComponent = MyCoolHeaderComponent;
```

You will have to provide your own UI and functionality for the header (in your MyCoolHeaderComponent class).

Answer (score 1):

`MatDatepicker` component uses `DateAdapter` service to handle dates, and when you click on next or previous button, a handler runs on `MatCalendarHeader` component and this handler calls `addCalendarMonths` method on `DateAdapter` (if current view is `month`) so if you patch this function on `DateAdapter` service TEMPORARILY, you can do anything you like, for example:

1. in parent component

```
origAddCalendarMonths: any
constructor(@Optional() private _dateAdapter: DateAdapter<any>) { }

onOpenedStream() {
   this.origAddCalendarMonths = this._dateAdapter.addCalendarMonths
   this._dateAdapter.addCalendarMonths = (...args) => {
     console.log('!!!')
     // your logic
     return this.origAddCalendarMonths.apply(this._dateAdapter, args)
   }
}

onClosedStream() {
    this._dateAdapter.addCalendarMonths = this.origAddCalendarMonths
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.onClosedStream()
}
```

or if you use `MatCalendar` instead, you can provide some extended class from `DateAdapter` in parent component providers to provide that class as `DateAdapter` for all child of this component (`NodeInjector`)